# Tridiagonal With Constant Off-Diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, tridiagonal-matrices

Does anybody know about the eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix with constant off-diagonal elements?  Such a matrix can be rescaled into

$$ 
\left( \begin{array}{ccccccc}
a_1 & 1 & 0& \ldots  & & \\
1 & a_2 &1 & \ldots & & \\ 
0 & 1 & a_3 &\ldots &&\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &
 \vdots  \\
 & & & \ldots & a_{n-1} & 1 \\
& & & \ldots & 1 & a_n
\end{array} \right) $$

where $a=(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ is a real vector.

For the case where $a$ is proportional to the unit vector, this is done on MS in 
[Eigenvalues of a certain tridiagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530277/eigenvalues-of-a-certain-tridiagonal-matrix) . How would you go about for the general case?

Comment: It is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix. There are searchable results about that

Comment: Not just that, but the off-diagonals are constant.